# Drupal - best practice for database settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal, what is the best practice for configuring database settings (database, username, password, host, etc.)?

In `sites/default/default.settings.php` it states the following:

```
/**
 * Database settings:
 *
 * The $databases array specifies the database connection or
 * connections that Drupal may use.  Drupal is able to connect
 * to multiple databases, including multiple types of databases,
 * during the same request.
 *
 * One example of the simplest connection array is shown below. To use the
 * sample settings, copy and uncomment the code below between the @code and
 * @endcode lines and paste it after the $databases declaration. You will need
 * to replace the database username and password and possibly the host and port
 * with the appropriate credentials for your database system.
 *
 * The next section describes how to customize the $databases array for more
 * specific needs.
 *
 * @code
 * $databases['default']['default'] = array (
 *   'database' => 'databasename',
 *   'username' => 'sqlusername',
 *   'password' => 'sqlpassword',
 *   'host' => 'localhost',
 *   'port' => '3306',
 *   'driver' => 'mysql',
 *   'prefix' => '',
 *   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
 * );
 * @endcode
 */
 $databases = array();
```

But what if your development environment and your production environment will have different database settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal supports multisites. You can use that for multiple configurations for development, staging and production.

Create a folder in the `sites` folder with the name of your development, staging and production domains and each of them will have their own `settings.php` file which in turn means they will have separate database connection configurations. Drupal will auto-select the correct folder depending on the domain that is currently being used.

Usually I setup three folders:

- development.myproject.com
- staging.myproject.com
- myproject.com (production)

Configuring `sites.php` is optional if the folders you create are exactly the domain name. You can configure `sites.php` if you want to access via a path (e.g. `myproject.com/devel`).

Some more info in the [Drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base).